# How to take React Native app offline built using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to Expo and React Native.

Question:
How would I take the app offline (disable the app service for 1 day, maybe turn off the server temporarily), NOT take off from playstore or AppStore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking it off the playStore and AppStore might be a lengthy process and then re-listing might include more wait times.

In this case, you could disable the service temporarily.
To do this, go on the server where the service is being hosted for example: `Docker`/`IIS`

and STOP the service for the desired period, the App would still be available but the new/existing users wouldn't be able to use it.

This worked.